# Is there is any way to get all instances in ec2 across all regions php SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

is there is any way to get all instances across all regions in aws ec2 rest API or SDK?

I need all instances in ec2 all regions ('us-east-1','us-west-1','us-west-2','ca-central-1','eu-west-1','eu-central-1','eu-west-2','ap-northeast-1','ap-southeast-1','ap-southeast-2','ap-south-1','sa-east-1')

Answer (score 1):

Create a list with regions and iterate through it.

```
region = ["us-east-1", "us-west-2"]
for i in region:
    ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=i)
    response = ec2_client.describe_instances()
```

Comment: That example is in Python, but PHP should be similar.

Comment: I tried it the same way, it works but it will run loop in all region. it is time taking. I am having 300 plus instances in each region